# javascript drop-down menu not working with Chrome (event issue?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, menu

My generated drop-down menu works in Firefox and IE but not Google Chrome.  I have

```
function characterList(){
    //code removed that generates select list 
    var optionContainer = document.createElement("option");
    optionContainer.innerHTML = "Show All Character Lines";
    addEvent(optionContainer, "click", filterChar, false);
    selectContainer.appendChild(optionContainer); //appends option to select menu

    for (var i = 0; i < menu_lines; i++){
       var optionContainer1 = document.createElement("option");
       optionContainer1.innerHTML = "blah" //simplified so that names in menu are all "blah"
       selectContainer.appendChild(optionContainer1);//appends option to select menu
       addEvent(optionContainer1, "click", filterChar, false);//I think the problem is here.
    }
}

function filterChar(){
    alert("filterChar");
}


function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}
```

characterList populates a drop-down menu (of the select option type) with the names taken from h3 headings of an HTML file.  This works fine.  The problem is that in Google Chrome filterChar is not called on drop-down menu clicks.  I have a function given to me (attachEvent) that's supposed to be all-browser compatible.  Please someone help.

Comment: Could you minimize the code while reproducing the issue?

Comment: @Tobias Springer :  I tried to simplify it.  What is left is basically the creation of each option creation.

Comment: @user963070 Chrome should tell you exactly what the problem is in the javascript console (F12 or rightclick > inspect element)

Comment: So you only call addEvent for each option , but not for the select? is that right?

Comment: @Tobias Springer  Right.  The first index 0 entry in select was different from the others, so it is made an option separately.  I tried the Javascript Console, but it had no entries.  I have never used it before.  I don't know if I am using it correctly.

Comment: so your problem is that if you click on an option nothing happens?

Comment: @TobiasSpringer  Yes.  Sorry that was not clear.

Comment: You need to attach the event to the `select`. `onchange` will fire when the selection has changed.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the best solution

Comment: @Stecman I do not completely understand why it works, but it works!!!  If you post the solution, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a single event listener to your `select` element. Option elements aren't regular DOM elements which is why listening to their `onclick` doesn't work.

Attaching a single `onchange` event listener to a select will fire when the selection has changed:

```
addEvent(selectContainer, "change", filterChar, false);
```

You can get reference to the select in the callback function using the event object passed as the first parameter:

```
function filterChar(e){
    var select = e.target;
    alert("The selected item was index "+select.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Can you use "click" instead of "change?"  That worked for me.

Comment: Yep, and most of the [other event types](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#events). Use what suits your needs.